# Looking for a player that can change the background of an RGBA video

Tags: video, linux, vlc

Is there a Video Player for Linux where I can play a RGBA .mov file and set a Background Color? VLC is displaying transparency as black and I've found no way to change that.

I know that OBS is capable of doing it but I'm looking for a way to play the video via CLI or a Python script.

regards
Matthias